# How do I get a ref to xgrid component from @material-ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to get a global (window) reference to the xgrid compenent so I can interact with it from other elements on the page. The following code returns a reference called xgridComponent to the javascript window, but the reference is simply tied to the html div tag the uses. It does not have access to the state nor functions of the component itself. Can someone show me what I am doing wrong please?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
//import { DataGrid } from '@material-ui/data-grid';
import { XGrid } from '@material-ui/x-grid';
import "regenerator-runtime/runtime";

function filterModelChanged()
{
    console.log(this.getSortModel());
    console.log(this.state.filter.items);
}

function ReaderWorklist({ initialRows, columns }) {
    const [rows, setRows] = useState(initialRows);

    return (
        <div style={{ height: 600, width: '100%' }}>
        <XGrid rows={rows} columns={columns} onFilterModelChange={filterModelChanged} ref={(xgridComponent) => {window.xgridComponent = xgridComponent}} />
            </div>
    );
}

//
async function getData() {
    let response = await fetch("/services/reader_worklist_services/getList",
                                {credentials:"same-origin"});
    return await response.text();
}

//Need to wait till all elements are present before 'latching' onto them with the react componenet
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    getData().then(function(data) {
        const rootElement = document.getElementById('reader_worklist_container');
        const jsData = JSON.parse(data);
        ReactDOM.render(<ReaderWorklist initialRows={jsData.rows} columns={jsData.columns} />, rootElement);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Move `filterModelChanged` into `ReaderWorkList`. There you should declare also `getSortModel` method and initiate the `filter` state.
Also, since `ReaderWorkList` is a function component, `this` is not what you think it does and you shouldn't use it.

Something like

```
function ReaderWorklist({ initialRows, columns }) {
  const [rows, setRows] = useState(initialRows);
  const [filter, setFilter] = useState({
    items: [],
  });

  function getSortModel() {
    // return something
  }

  function filterModelChanged() {
    console.log(getSortModel());
    console.log(filter.items);
  }

  return (
    <div style={{ height: 600, width: '100%' }}>
      <XGrid
        rows={rows}
        columns={columns}
        onFilterModelChange={filterModelChanged}
        ref={(xgridComponent) => {
          window.xgridComponent = xgridComponent;
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```